# Ruby on Rails - rollback on transactions doesnt work for multiple saves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I have this simple piece of code.

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    User.new(username: "michael").save!
    User.new(username: "lebron").save!
    User.new(username: "michael").save! # not unique error
end
```

Fun fact is that error in the 3rd line doesn't rollback all saves, but just the last one.

What am I not understanding about TX in Ruby so it behaves like that?

I know [from documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-save+and+destroy+are+automatically+wrapped+in+a+transaction) that

> Both #save and #destroy come wrapped in a transaction

So I assume they are wrapped into a different one then the parent transaction.

Thuss making rollback from the 3rd statement not effective on the two prior ones.

How that should be addressed, so I have all statements rolled back during the course of the transaction?

Comment: I cannot actually reproduce this. Are you sure the validation is actually working? See https://gist.github.com/maxcal/ab62b800447fe0cb9914f519ab1e7fd3

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ActiveRecord::Base.transaction will verify a single transaction so you can convert this into a single transaction so that it will work properly. So push user details into an array and create it.

Example:
`user_details = [{username: "michael"}, {username: "lebron"}, {username: "michael"}] User.create(user_details)`